# Find Taylor series for $\sec^2 (x)$ as far as the term containing $x^6$ by expanding $\sec ^2(x)$ as a geometric series in $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: calculus

We could have $\sec ^2(x)$ = $\frac{1}{\cos ^2(x)}=\frac{1}{1-\sin^2(x)}$

Now using $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum \limits _{n=0}^\infty x^n$, we could have $\frac{1}{1-\sin^2(x)}=\sum \limits _{n=0}^\infty \sin^{2n}(x)$. I am not sure of where this is going. I also do not see how I will get powers of $x$ up to $x^6$ from what I have. Please can you shed some light.

Comment: Do you know the power series for sine? If so, you can square it, and track the terms up to $x^6$. Then you can square that to get the fourth power, and track the relevant terms. In this way you can continue until you have all the terms you are asked for.

Comment: Thanks @A. Thomas Yerger, I get it now.

Comment: $ secx = 1+ \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{5x^4}{4!} + \frac{61x^6}{6!} + .... $ Look up about the Boustrophedon table for its derivation.